# get class values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

given a class .test{color:red;....}, how do i get the style propertise by using javascript?

Comment: Please explain better and provide some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Add a little more information. What are you trying to achieve? Do you have some code for us to read? etc.

Comment: Do you need css properties? If yes -  var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );

Comment: I need the css properties even if the class is not currently used on the page.

Comment: Help u re-define questions: given a class .test{color:red;....}, how do i get the style propertise by using javascript?

Comment: Thanks @Stupidfrog
Thats what I meant

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assume you need the properties even if the class is not present at the moment, consider the following:

1. Create an element with that class on the fly
2. Get its styles
3. Remove it again

Example:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    var $bar, styles,
        markup = '<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>';

    // add a temporary element
    $('body').append( markup );

    // get element
    $bar = $('#bar');

    // get style with jQuery.css
    console.log( $bar.css('margin') );

    // or: Get all computed styles
    styles = getComputedStyle( $bar[0] );

    // all computed styles
    console.log( styles );
    // read out the one you want
    console.log( styles.margin );

    // for more see 
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle

    // remove the element again
    $bar.remove().detach();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkzb0726/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the title of an element with class then it is some what similar to below code...

**jQuery Code**

```
$(selector).attr(attribute);
```

If you want to get the inline styles then use

```
$(".test").css('style');
```

After this you need to parse the string and base on the separator. Then you will get the key / value pairs of css properties.

In the same way if you want to get the css properties then

**jQuery Code**

```
$(selector).css(proprerty);

$(".test").css('width');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/s2xcmsvx/